# DyanmoDb is storing value 1 instead of boolean value true

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, boolean

I have a method which is simply storing flag value true for a particular record. My flag attribute has been defined as Boolean which has value true/false in my DynamoDB database. 
While running this method, somehow instead of storing true value, it is inserting a new column for the flag attribute as number datatype and writing value 1 instead of true. While debugging I can see it is reading the value as "true" but while writing my guess is it is taking 1 for true and 0 for false, and hence writing 1.

```
public static ArrayList<UserWishListBuks> removeNotification(int Statusid) {
    AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = NavigationDrawerActivity.clientManager
            .ddb();
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddb);
    DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
    Boolean value = true;
    try{
        PaginatedScanList<UserWishListBuks> result = mapper.scan(
                UserWishListBuks.class, scanExpression);
        for (UserWishListBuks bre : result) {
            if( (bre.getBOOK_STATUS_ID()==(Statusid))   )
            {
                bre.setNOTIFICATION_FLAG(true);
                mapper.save(bre);
            }
        }
    }catch (AmazonServiceException ex) {
        NavigationDrawerActivity.clientManager
                .wipeCredentialsOnAuthError(ex);
    }
    return null;
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's expected, have a look at the datatypes docs for dynamodb: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html

The Java type of Boolean will be stored as a number type in dynamodb, 0 or 1.
Alternatively, you can use `@DynamoDBNativeBooleanType` to map a Java `Boolean` to the DynamoDB `BOOL` data type

Comment: This is absent in latest versions.

@DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBAttributeType.BOOL)
@DynamoDBAttribute

is the new way.

Answer (score 32):

DynamoDb will store the boolean value as 0 or 1 by default.

Use the following decorators to save the attribute as `false` or `true` respectively.

```
@DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBAttributeType.BOOL)
@DynamoDBAttribute
private boolean notificationFlag;
```

Note: `@DynamoDBNativeBoolean` which used to do this is [deprecated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBNativeBoolean.html)